# Using `std::experimental::propagate_const` for arrays

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, const-correctness

The question is simple: why can't I use [`propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) for arrays?

The following line gives errors:

```
std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<int[]>> ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(1);
```

The errors (gcc version 13.0):

```
/usr/local/include/c++/13.0.0/experimental/propagate_const: In Instanziierung von »struct std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::__propagate_const_conversions<std::unique_ptr<int []> >«:
/usr/local/include/c++/13.0.0/experimental/propagate_const:108:11:   erfordert durch »class std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<int []> >«
../../livews2223/l00/main.cpp:182:64:   von hier erfordert
/usr/local/include/c++/13.0.0/experimental/propagate_const:55:37: Fehler: no match for »operator*« (operand type is »std::unique_ptr<int []>«)
55 |       = remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<_Tp&>())>;
|                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The the goal is to prevent that a const element-function can change array elements like:

```
struct A {
    void foo() const {
        a[0] = 2; // should not be possible
    }
//    std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<int[]>> a = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);    
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> a = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique_ptr<T[]>` is neither a pointer nor a pointer-like type. It's an *array*-like type. That's why it has `operator[]` but not `operator*`. It makes little sense to use `*ptr` on an array (for language arrays, this accesses the first element, but using `ptr[0]` makes it much more clear what's going on). So `unique_ptr<T[]>` provides no such operator.

And therefore, it isn't pointer-like enough for `propagate_const` to work.

Comment: I just edited to question to make it clearer what I am trying to do.

Comment: @wimalopaan: You would have to write your own version of `propagate_const` that works on arrays, overloading `operator[]` appropriately.